# jdbctemplate return multple rows with dynamic sql

Tags: java, jdbctemplate

I have a method which needs to return a list of Strings from a DB.

```
private static List<String> getUserForAccount(final String account) {
   String sql = "SELECT NAME FROM CLIENTS WHERE ACCOUNT = ?";
```

}

I am unsure which jdbcTemplate method is the best to use for this situation. I don't think I can use queryForList() because the SQL has a parameter.

Any suggestions would be welcome .

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [`JdbcTemplate`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html?is-external=true) API. You argument that *"I don't think I can use queryForList() because the SQL has a parameter"* really doesn't make much sense. I think all the `queryForList()` takes parameters, which is the parameter `Object[] args`, as in

- [`List<Map<String,Object>> queryForList(String sql, Object[] args, int[] argTypes`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#queryForList%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%5b%5d,%20int%5b%5d%29)

There are many overloaded methods for `queryForList()` but I think this is the one you want. Basically just pass your query, an array of arguments, which will only be `account` in your case, and pass the db [`Types` (int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Types.html?is-external=true) argument. Something like

```
public class SomeDaoImpl extends JdbcTemplate implements SomeDao {
    private static final String NAME_BY_ACCOUNT = 
                                "SELECT NAME FROM CLIENTS WHERE ACCOUNT = ?"

    public List<Map<String, Object>> getUsernameByAccount(String account) {
        return (List<Map<String, Object>>) queryForList(
                                           NAME_BY_ACCOUNT,
                                           new Object[] { account },
                                           new int[] { Types.VARCHAR });
    }
}
```

The key returns will be the name of the column. Then you can iterate the list of maps like

```
List<Map<String, Object>> result = someDao.getUsernameByAccount(account);
for (Map map : result) {
    System.out.println(map.get("NAME"));
}
```

---

You may also find some interest in some of the overloaded `query()` methods, which take variations of `PreparedStatementSetter` and `RowMapper`. Look at the API I linked above

Comment: Thank You! Yes my argument didn't make any sense... apologies.